# Как запустить bash-скрипт из кода?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, rust

Пытаюсь выполнить скрипт из кода так:

```
Command::new("sh ~/game/src/f.sh").status(); // когда запускаю ничего не происходит
```

Если ввести `sh ~/game/src/f.sh` непосредственно в терминал, то все работает правильно:

```
`Command::new("ls").status();`// работает правильно
```

В файле `f.sh` одна строка:

```
ls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) должно быть примерно так:

```
Command::new("sh").arg("~/game/src/f.sh").status();
```